# How to count some number on a while loop and order them from the biggest number?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, count

I have a shop, and in seller section I want to make a top8 sellers.
Accounts are saved on another table, users on another table.

I want to get users, and count their sold data, and order them like top 8 list goes.

How can I do that, what I need? I have no idea at all.

The database has columns of accounts data and their price, so I need  to count the price first.

Comment: is there any code we can have a look at? Anything you've tried? Hints: join, count, group by, order by.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY sales LIMIT 8` in the database query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to select all orders you have.
After that, you loop through them and sum their orders by user id:

```
$sums = array();
foreach($orders as $order){
    if(!isset($sums))
        $sums[$order['id_user']] = 0;
    $sums[$order['id_user']] += $order['order_value'];
    // order_value is sum of total products - meaning order value - I', not 
}
```

Now, you have `$sums` array filled with total spent by `user_id`.
Now all you have to do, is to sort them usint `arsort` ( http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php )

Now you have array, where first 8 rows are top buyers.